# Using probability or moment generating functions to find the distribution when given the distribution with random parameters

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Problem: Given  $X|M=m \sim $ Poi(m) with $M\sim $ Exp(1). Find the unconditional  distribution of X where M is the random parameter. I want to solve this using P.G.F $g(t)$ and/or M.G.F $\psi(t)$.

(If you find this post bad please leave a comment why before down voting as I am new here and want to learn from my mistakes. If it is ok I will remove this section, thanks!)

I am new with the probability and moment generating functions so can't understand why my way of solving the problem is incorrect (or maybe even correct).

$g_X(t)=E(t^X)=E(E(t^X|M))=E(h(M))$

$h(m)=E(t^X|M=m)=e^{m(t-1)}$

$E(h(M))=E(e^{M(t-1)})=\psi_M(t-1)=\frac{1}{1-(t-1)}=\frac{1}{2-t}=\frac{\frac{1}{2}}{1-\frac{1}{2}t}$

which happens to be the P.G.F for the geometric distribution with parameter 1/2. This seems right but I expected to obtain a moment generating function or does $\psi(g(t))=g(t)$ hold in general? If so does also the inverse relationship hold i.e. $g(\psi(t))=\psi(t)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your calculation is correct as written.

You got a PGF because you started with a PGF.  You wrote $$g_X(t) = \operatorname{E}[t^X] = \ldots.$$  So if this is how you began, your result will be a PGF.  It isn't because $\psi(g(t)) = g(t)$ or anything like that.  Had you attempted to begin by finding $\psi_X(t) = \operatorname{E}[e^{tX}] = \ldots$, you would have either gotten stuck (if the computation became intractable), or ended up with an expression for the MGF of $X$.