# Find the characteristic function of Y where Y|X=x $\in N(0, x)$ with X $\in Po(\lambda)$

Tags: probability-theory, normal-distribution, poisson-distribution, characteristic-functions

In particular $Var(Y|X=x)=x$. 
I think the solution should be the characteristic function for the $N(0,\lambda)$ distribution i.e. $\varphi_y(t)=e^{-\frac{1}{2}t^2\lambda}$ but I can't figure out why the last step fails to prove this.

The related questions help slightly but not enough unfortunately as I am new to this topic.

[Using probability or moment generating functions to find the distribution when given the distribution with random parameters](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1780999/using-probability-or-moment-generating-functions-to-find-the-distribution-when-g)

[Compound Distribution — Normal Distribution with Log Normally Distributed Variance](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1620949/compound-distribution-normal-distribution-with-log-normally-distributed-varian)

My attempt:

$\varphi_y(t)=E(e^{itY})=E(E(e^{itY}|M))=E(e^{-\frac{1}{2}t^2X})=\psi_x(-\frac{1}{2}t^2)=e^{\lambda(e^{-\frac{1}{2}t^2}-1)}$

From here I don't see that $e^{\lambda(e^{-\frac{1}{2}t^2}-1)}$ belongs to any special distribution. Does this mean that this is a dead end and I have to use a different method? Thanks!

Comment: "Does this mean that this is a dead end and I have to use a different method?" ?? Any other (correct) method will still yield $E(e^{itY})=\exp(-\lambda(1-e^{-t^2/2}))$ so what is the question?

Comment: Your computation is correct. At first sight, it looks like the characteristic function of a Poisson $(\lambda)$ distribution but it's not since you can't get rid of the square. However, I don't see why that is a problem? Using another method would lead to the same conclusion.